# System.Management.Automation lib for asp.net core 1.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I am trying to use "**System.Management.Automation**" library in my ASP.NET core App (.net core app 1.1). But I can not add it from nuget package manager. Can any one please suggest the supportatble version of lib for ASP.NET Core app 1.1.

Thanks,

Comment: have you looked [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2284)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official package on nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation/) is only for net4.0

There is a myget package available but you'd need to add the repository(s) to your nuget.config first:

```
<add key="dotnet-core" value="https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-core/api/v3/index.json" />
<add key="powershell-core" value="https://powershell.myget.org/F/powershell-core/api/v3/index.json" />
```

This should help to resolve the packages.

Comment: There is an pre-release version, but that worked for me. Thanks :)

Comment: @RamashankerTripathi in the nuget description it says: `6.1.7601.* are unofficial packages for .Net 4.0 `